# Modern best approach to using Django ORM with async?

Tags: django, python-asyncio, django-channels

The world of async Django is changing rapidly, and it's hard to tell what is current and what is dated.

So, what is the current best approach to using the Django ORM (or, possibly, another ORM) for the best/smoothest async capability?  What do people use successfully today?

Lots of references out there, including:

- https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/asynchronous-orm/5925/70
- https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/databases.html

One problem I have is that no matter what I try, I run into the "django.db.utils.OperationalError: database "test_djangoasyncproj" is being accessed by other users" issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using **Django >= 4.2**

> **Asynchronous support**
>
> Django has support for writing asynchronous (“async”) views, along
> with an entirely async-enabled request stack if you are running under
> ASGI. Async views will still work under WSGI, but with performance
> penalties, and without the ability to have efficient long-running
> requests.

```
async for author in Author.objects.filter(name__startswith="A"):
    book = await author.books.afirst()


async def make_book(*args, **kwargs):
    book = Book(...)
    await book.asave(using="secondary")


async def make_book_with_tags(tags, *args, **kwargs):
    book = await Book.objects.acreate(...)
    await book.tags.aset(tags)
```

source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/async/

Answer (score 8):

i think u should follow documentation
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/async/#asgiref.sync.sync_to_async
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/async/#async-views

```
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async

results = await sync_to_async(Blog.objects.get, thread_sensitive=True)(pk=123)
```

or

```
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async

def _get_blog(pk):
    return Blog.objects.select_related('author').get(pk=pk)

get_blog = sync_to_async(_get_blog, thread_sensitive=True)
```

Comment: Thanks.  That will work, but is hardly ideal.  It is ugly and awkward, and will surely need to be refactored when Django ORM supports async properly.

Comment: @ScottStafford can u mark this answer as correct one?