# Using Django 4.1 async orm in FastAPi

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, django-orm, fastapi

In verson 4.1 some async stuff was added to orm part of Django. I want to use Django orm in fastAPi, I created a small setting file for using Django orm like this:

```
import os
import sys
import django
from django.conf import settings

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'orm',
]
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'db',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'pass',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
settings.configure(
    DATABASES = DATABASES,
    INSTALLED_APPS = INSTALLED_APPS,
)
django.setup()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

I want to run a query is main file like this in FastApi:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
@app.get("/test-orm")
async def test_django_orm():
    results = await User.objects.filter(username="user0")
    paginator = Paginator(results, 2)
    paginated = json.loads(serializers.serialize('json', paginator.page(1)))
    return {"data": paginated}
```

This code simple doesn't work! here is error:

```
TypeError: object QuerySet can't be used in 'await' expression
```

If I remove async and await it works perfectly, but I write to use async friendly code!

Comment: seems you have to async the filter call then await the result see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/4.1/#asynchronous-orm-interface), also, starting a django webserver process just for using its orm seems a bit bloathed, why not use sqlalchemy?

Comment: Thanks, but learning sqlalchemy takes time :) and I'm not sure it is a good investment or not

Comment: What does "simply doesn't work" mean? Do you get any errors? What's the expected result? What happens? Your FastAPI code also seems to be written in a way that differs from how you'd usually use FastAPI (manually serializing, returning a dict instead of a pydantic model, etc.). Are you sure you're not better off by using Django REST Framework instead?

Comment: Sorry for over simplification, I added error :) My idea was using FastAPi using django ORM, In the documenttion of FastAPi it is mentioned that it is possible. https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/

Answer (score 0):

As you may read in documentation or other related threads in SO, you should use function `sync_to_async` from `asgiref`. Take a look here:

[Modern best approach to using Django ORM with async?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71081084/modern-best-approach-to-using-django-orm-with-async)

and here in documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/async/#asgiref.sync.sync_to_async

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/async/#async-views

Answer (score 0):

you can use django-async-orm module for the async DB calls.

and you can read the docs here:
https://github.com/rednaks/django-async-orm

Only issue with the module is, it is still in development phase, means it is not for production.